# How to process files which are uploaded in google cloud storage for validation in cloud function

Tags: google-cloud-functions, cloud

How to process files which are uploaded in google cloud storage (Java)

I have to unzip all the files which are uploaded in cloud storage in google cloud function.

Basically i need to check file formats of the files within zip folder.

Is there any way to download it in cloud function ?Is it right way to do

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Using Cloud Functions triggered by Cloud Storage (GCS) events is a common and good practice:

https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/calling/storage#functions-calling-storage-java

When an object is uploaded to GCS, one or more Cloud Functions is triggered, uses the Cloud Storage client library:

https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/reference/libraries

To:

1. unzip the object
2. enumerate its content
3. process (check file types etc.)
4. Do something with the result

> **NOTE** events only arise on changes so you'll likely want to consider a mechanism that reconciles the source bucket's content for zipped files that e.g. existed prior to the trigger's deployment